# Debounce in React component JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing a simple debounce function for an input component

```
export const debounce = (func, wait) => {
    let timeout
    return function (...args) {
        if (timeout) {
            clearTimeout(timeout)
        }
        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            timeout = null
            Reflect.apply(func, this, args)
        }, wait)
    }
}
```

it imported from an external file, and used as a wrap for `input` onKeyUp handler inside a React component (Hooks)

```
const handleChange = debounce(() => console.log("test"), 1000)
```

PROBLEM: I'm getting "test" log every time when text in `input` changes, not only one - as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the whole component using `handleChange = debounce(...`?

Comment: Yes please show the components because it works fine in my codesandbox

Comment: @mgm793 Did you try it with Hooks version or Class?

Comment: The Hooks version with Functions

Comment: @mgm793 it is true, no problem with the direct bind to onChange, but onKeyUp attached to the same input - problem reappear. Also it appears if I trying to run it from the body of onChange function

Comment: What is Reflect and why bind `this`? I think the code should be: `func.apply(null, args)` and when you want to bind something to the debounced function you can do: `const boundHandler = debounce(fn.bind(this),timeout)` With functional components you don't need to bind anything.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is the problem with your code but here is a version with hooks working

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useDebounce = (value, delay) => {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = setTimeout(() => setDebouncedValue(value), delay);
    return () => clearTimeout(handler);
  }, [value, delay]);

  return debouncedValue;
};

export default useDebounce;
```

and then you use it as

```
const debouncedValue = useDebounce(inputValue, delay);
```